# Records coming from search api not resetting in search screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I hope you can help with this, it has been weeks i am trying to solve this issue, did many google search but none of the solutions worked. I am trying to build a search screen in which i have a search text input and a select list which defines the type of search. In the type of searches i have: "News, Videos, Documentaries, Channels" so based on which selected type the results should be back as news or videos or documentaries or channels. So the user enters his search text and the default selected category is News so when he clicked on search button results are displayed under the search form on the same screen. If he stays on the same screen and make search again but this time he changes the type lets say to videos, the results are appended to the news and not replaced. I want them to be replacing the news results from the previous search. Can you help me please do that ? Which means i am not able to reset the result data render. I am trying also to include an infinite scrolling feature.

here is my search screen code:

```
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    FlatList,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppTextInput from '../components/AppTextInput';
import Card from '../components/Card';

import colors from '../config/colors';

import axios from 'axios';
import { baseApiUrl, apikey } from '../api/config/apiLinks';
import AppPicker from '../components/AppPicker';
import AppText from '../components/AppText';
import { openBrowserAsync } from 'expo-web-browser';

const options = [
    { value: 'news', label: 'News' },
    { value: 'videos', label: 'Videos' },
    { value: 'documentaries', label: 'Documentaries' },
    { value: 'channels', label: 'Channels' },
];

export default function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]);
    const [input, setInput] = useState();

    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState();
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    const [resultRecords, setResultRecords] = useState([]);

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
    const [previousType, setPreviousType] = useState('');

    const url =
        baseApiUrl +
        '/search/search-get.php?' +
        apikey +
        '&category=' +
        selected.value +
        '&q=' +
        input +
        '&page=' +
        currentPage +
        '&count=15';

    const loadSearchResult = () => {
        if (input.length > 2) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    setErrorMessage('');
                    setTotalPages(response.data.totalPages);
                    console.log('new request ----');
                    console.log('selected: ', selected);
                    console.log('previousType: ', previousType);
                    if (selected.value !== previousType) {
                        setResultRecords([]);
                    }
                    if (!scrolling) {
                        setResultRecords(response.data.data);
                    } else {
                        setResultRecords([
                            ...resultRecords,
                            ...response.data.data,
                        ]);
                    }
                    setScrolling(false);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setPreviousType(selected.value);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.response.status == 404) {
                        setErrorMessage('Results not found!');
                    }
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setScrolling(false);
                });
        }
    };

    const onInputChange = (text) => {
        if (text != '') {
            setInput(text);
        }
    };

    const loadMoreRecords = () => {
        setScrolling(true);
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    };

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            // Do something when the screen is focused

            return () => {
                // Do something when the screen is unfocused
                // Useful for cleanup functions
                setResultRecords([]);
                setErrorMessage('');
                setInput('');
                setSelected(options[0]);
            };
        }, [])
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                <AppTextInput
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    icon="magnify"
                    onFieldChange={onInputChange}
                    defaultValue={input}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                <AppPicker
                    selectedItem={selected}
                    onSelectItem={(item) => {
                        setSelected(item);
                    }}
                    items={options}
                    icon="apps"
                    placeholder="Category"
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button
                    title="Search"
                    onPress={() => {
                        loadSearchResult();
                    }}
                />
            </View>

            {isLoading ? (
                <View style={styles.loaderStyle}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#aaa" />
                </View>
            ) : (
                <View style={styles.results}>
                    {errorMessage == '' ? (
                        <FlatList
                            data={resultRecords}
                            keyExtractor={(records) => {
                                records.id.toString() +
                                    records.title.toString();
                            }}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <Card
                                    title={item.title}
                                    feedName={item.feedName}
                                    date={item.pubDate}
                                    imageUrl={item.image}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        if (selected.value == 'news') {
                                            navigation.navigate(
                                                'NewsDetailsScreen',
                                                item
                                            );
                                        } else if (selected.value == 'videos') {
                                            navigation.navigate(
                                                'YoutubeVideoDetailsScreen',
                                                item
                                            );
                                        } else if (
                                            selected.value == 'documentaries'
                                        ) {
                                            openBrowserAsync(item.link);
                                        } else if (
                                            selected.value == 'channels'
                                        ) {
                                            openBrowserAsync(item.link);
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            )}
                            //ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
                            onEndReached={loadMoreRecords}
                            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <AppText style={styles.results}>{errorMessage}</AppText>
                    )}
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loaderStyle: {
        marginVertical: 16,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    container: {
        padding: 15,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        // backgroundColor: colors.light,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width: '100%',
    },
    innerContainer: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    button: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 15,
    },
    results: {
        marginTop: 15,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});
```